# Conditional Formatting Using Cell References in Google Sheets (for a teacher modifying a pixel art activity)

Tags: math, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

Thank you all in advance for helping this tired middle school math teacher try to bring some fun to class on Monday (Halloween). We will be doing a math lab on ratios of colors of Skittles in a fun size bag. I have a Google Sheets document that generates a picture of Frida Kahlo when answers are entered correctly. It was previously used as a fraction/decimal/percent activity so you'll see that the "answers" are still all fractions that have nothing to do with Monday's activity. I left them there so that it would be easier to find the conditional formatting that populates the image/pixel art.

My problem is that each student will have a different bag of skittles so they will have varying amounts of each color. At the top of the page I left boxes for students to type in the amount of each color in their bag as well as the total number of Skittles in their bag. I'd like the "answers" cells to then pull from the data they typed in so the conditional formatting will work for every student. For example, the question that says "red to purple" (last question in the first column) needs to pull their value from T4 and AZ4. Ideally, a student would type in the answer **5:4** using a colon and the corresponding parts of the Frida Kahlo picture would appear.

My conditional formatting is not advanced enough to be able to reference a cell, insert a colon, and reference another cell.

Link to view: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m2v7KrgqSXiPOe3rn1uYyDfR8Tv1vc7FOZFpwGoc7RI/edit#gid=1536043985

I have already successful put in the coding for the questions labeled "first blank" through "seventh blank" as the answers are just words from a fill in the blank activity we will do in class. [answers to first 7 blanks if it's helpful: ratio, part, whole, part, to, colon, fraction]

I have attempted to use my limited knowledge of referencing cells and using concatenation to make this happen but I was unsuccessful. I simply cannot get it to pull the data correctly with a colon : between the numbers.

Even more complex will be the answers to the questions I highlighted in red on the document...For example, the question that says "green to orange and yellow" will have an answer of 6:7. The six can be pulled from AB4 but the seven is the sum of AR4+AJ4. And, of course, a colon in the middle.

For the question that says "red to not red" the answer is 5:15. The five is pulled from T4 and the fifteen is BH4-T4.

I have looked through many other posts but cannot find exactly what I need to make this work. Apologies if I missed a post that has this answer. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're going to use the same system you have (Conditional formatting based on a formula) for all of the different types of comparisons that you have.

The first is for simple comparisons (one color to one color). For example, this is for Red to Purple. The current conditional formatting is:

```
=$C$73<>"23/100"
```

All you'll need to do is change that rule to the following:

```
=$C$73<>CONCATENATE($T$4&":"&$AZ$4)
```

For the complex ones, you can use simple operators (+ -) to make those happen. This one is for the Green to Orange and Yellow:

```
=$CJ$37<>CONCATENATE($AB$4&":"&$AJ$4+$AR$4)
```

Happy Halloween!

Comment: Thank you so very much! I am crying happy tears!

Comment: In case anyone wants to see the finished product I'll be sharing with students, here's a link! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z-wr7k_G8PAB_lKNiPGYo6IuOwiTmxE1pPZC8JucoK8/edit?usp=sharing